# Stats on edits for answers to questions

Tags: discussion, site-stats

I just posted a beginner question son Stack Overflow 
[Python why would you use [:] over =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433759/python-why-would-you-use-over)

I got three one line answers to my questions with in 30 sec (Great job!) but I can't accept a answer for 10 mins (understandable).

I watched the question over the next few mins and saw that I got a total of 6 one line answers followed by many consecutive edits on the one line answers. The user edited their answers expanding on the original answer adding more details, code examples, and updating their answers with extra bits of information from each others answers.

For example about the 3 mins mark one user updated their answers to include a note that this was very important for lists. When he updated his answer, the following min all of the other answers also got updated with this tidbit.

Out of curiosity I was wondering how many edits does a normal answer get?

Comment: A very simple question or a question that looks simple (I assume yours is, since it got 6 answers) will receive an initial short answer, followed by many successive edits. This is a trick of the answerers to earn rep. An answer can be edited as many times as some limit allows (a few seconds per edit, not sure the exact number), and within 5 mins, there will be no revisioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those edits all fall into the "grace period" of five minutes where the edit is not recorded in any public place.

While there are tools (like [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)) allowing ordinary users to perform various queries over the database and get information and stats, edits within grace period are not recorded as far as I know, only devs can see it in some low level layer.

So I fear the answer is that calculating average number of edits is not possible with the current tools offered to us. (That is edits inclduing those made within grace periods, not just revisions which should be possible to get and calculate)

That said, from own experience what you describe usually result in 2-3 edits, then the user who answer either leave it be or delete his own answer if other was posted before with same logic and he can't find anything to add.